# knockoutjs template not working

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-templates

I was following a video about knockout and I have no idea why my code is not working.

I'm using these js scripts:

```
    <script src="assets/js/knockout-2.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.tmpl.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    

<h2>Friends</h2>
    <ul data-bind="template: {name: 'friendsTemplate', foreach:friends}"></ul>

    <script type="text/html" id="friendsTemplate">
        <li>${ data.name }</li>
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function friend(name) {
        return { name : ko.observable(name) };
    }

    var viewModel = {
        friends : ko.observableArray([new friend('João'), new friend('Lucas')])
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

This code returns me this, it is showing the correct amount of friends but not displaying the names.

```
Friends
${ data.name }
${ data.name }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Making some tests and this code works because it is not using template, so my code is correct, the problem is only with template.

```
<script type="text/html" id="friendsTemplate">
    <li><span data-bind="text: name"></span></li>
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should reference jquery.tmpl prior to knockoutjs

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.tmpl.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/knockout-2.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and change ${ data.name } to ${name}

http://jsfiddle.net/c8Svk/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script type="text/html" id="friendsTemplate">
    <li>$data.name</li>
</script>
```

Alternatively, you could just do:

```
<script type="text/html" id="friendsTemplate">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</script>
```