# Knockoutjs is not working

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am started learning knockoutjs and I have faced an error. The Aptana editor shows an error at the:

```
data-bind: ....
```

property of the tag complaining that it is a proprietary tag. I have made sure to include all the needed javascript files plus I have checked a prior question:[knockoutjs template not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277588/knockoutjs-template-not-working).
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  
        <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.8.2.min.js'></script>
        <script src='jquery.tmpl.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
        <script src='knockout-2.2.0.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
            function AppViewModel() {
                this.firstName = "Bert";
                this.lastName = "Bertington";
            }

            ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());       
        </script>
        <p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
        <p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Even after ignoring Aptana and hoping that the browser will show it I still get nothing. I am using Firefox 16 but I also tried on IE 8 but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your script tag underneath your markup.

```
<body>
    <p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
    <p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>
    <script>
        function AppViewModel() {
            this.firstName = "Bert";
            this.lastName = "Bertington";
        }

        ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());       
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Great it worked, but why? Why does the script should be after the markup? Is the how it should be for all the scripts I will be writing?

Comment: The DOM hasn't loaded before the script executes. Another alternative would be to wrap it in [jQuery's `ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function. `$(function() { ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel()); });`

Comment: Script tags inline with your markup are executed synchronously with the browser's processing of that markup, so as `sghill` noted the DOM elements were not ready when you tried to apply bindings.  By moving the script to the bottom you guarantee that the DOM elements you target will be available.  Alternatively, using a jQuery `ready` callback will ensure your code doesn't run until the DOM is loaded.  See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html... search for Activating Knockout.